# Getting infinite loop on a switch statement in java

Tags: java, switch-statement, infinite-loop

I'm having a problem with this program i'm trying to write for my homework. Here's the problem and the code I wrote:

A mail-order house sells five products whose retail prices are as 
follows :
Product 1: $2.98, Product 2: $4.50, Product 3: $9.98, Product 4: $4.49 and 
Product 5: $6.87. Write an application that reads a series of pairs of numbers as 
follows: 
A.
product number
B.
quantity sold
Your program should use 
switch
 statement to determine the retail price for each 
product. It should calculate and display the total retail value of all products sold. 
Use a sentinel-controlled loop to determine when the program should stop 
looping and display the final results.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program5
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        double totalCost1 = 0, totalCost2 = 0, totalCost3 = 0, totalCost4 = 0, totalCost5 = 0;

        System.out.println("Please enter the product number 1-5. Enter 0 to stop. :");

        int productNumber=keyboard.nextInt();

        while(productNumber!=0)
        {
            switch (productNumber)
            {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Enter quantity sold :");
                    double product1=keyboard.nextDouble();
                    totalCost1 = (2.98*product1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Enter quantity sold :");
                    double product2=keyboard.nextDouble();
                    totalCost2 = (4.50*product2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Enter Quantity sold :");
                    double product3=keyboard.nextDouble();
                    totalCost3 = (9.98*product3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Enter Quantity sold :");
                    double product4=keyboard.nextDouble();
                    totalCost4 = (4.49*product4);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Enter Quantity sold :");
                    double product5=keyboard.nextDouble();
                    totalCost5 = (6.87*product5);
                    break;
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("Product 1: %.2f%nProduct 2: %.2f%nProduct 3: %.2f%nProduct 4: %.2f%nProduct 5: %.2f%n", totalCost1, totalCost2, totalCost3, totalCost4, totalCost5);
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it asks to enter the product number. After I enter any number 1-5, it asks for the quantity sold. When I give any number, it keeps asking for quantity sold over and over, what did I do wrong?

Comment: You never set `productNumber` to `0`.

Comment: it still loops even if i set it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems in your code:

> 1) No default case
>
> 2) You need to ask the user inside loop again to enter `0` to exit the
>   loop:

So,

> 1) Add `default: break;` inside switch
>
> 2) Add below code after the switch statement:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the product number 1-5. Enter 0 to stop. :");
productNumber=keyboard.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need looping until get all products? If you need only 1 product you can remove the following loop

```
   while(productNumber!=0)
```

If you can get multiple products add the following line after switch statement to get next product:

```
  productNumber=keyboard.nextInt();
```